# After export data table to excel in C#, some cells' data messed up in excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, export-to-excel

I am able to export the datatable to excel in C#, however, some of the cells filled up with string "##########################" instead of the corrected cell value. Anyone know why it happens and how to solve the problem?

Comment: i think those are datetime columns you need to expand the column width to see the actual datetime value.

Comment: i never understood why they added that feature into excel

Answer (score 1):

i think those are datetime columns.
you need to expand the column width to see the actual datetime value.

Check the following pictures:

before expanding the DateTime column width(it shows #########)
[image]

after expanding the DateTime column width(it shows actual datetime value)
[image]